# MYSQL Query Error - Part 1 runs fine - Part 2 does not

Tags: mysql, sql

The instructors for the problem are
"Generate the following two result sets:

1. Query an alphabetically ordered list of all names in OCCUPATIONS, immediately followed by the first letter of each profession as a parenthetical (i.e.: enclosed in parentheses). For example: AnActorName(A), ADoctorName(D), AProfessorName(P), and ASingerName(S).
2. Query the number of ocurrences of each occupation in OCCUPATIONS. Sort the occurrences in ascending order, and output them in the following format:
   `There are a total of [occupation_count] [occupation]s.`

   where [occupation_count] is the number of occurrences of an occupation in OCCUPATIONS and [occupation] is the lowercase occupation name. If more than one Occupation has the same [occupation_count], they should be ordered alphabetically.

Input Format

The OCCUPATIONS table is described as follows

[image]

Occupation will only contain one of the following values: Doctor, Professor, Singer or Actor

Sample Output will be:

```
Christeen(P)
Jane(A)
Jenny(D)
Julia(A)
Ketty(P)
Maria(A)
Meera(S)
Priya(S)
Samantha(D)
There are a total of 2 doctors.
There are a total of 2 singers.
There are a total of 3 actors.
There are a total of 3 professors.
```

**This is the beginning of my code:**

```
SELECT NAME, 
        CONCAT('(', LEFT(OCCUPATION,1),')')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
ORDER BY NAME, OCCUPATION DESC


SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ' , COUNT(OCCUPATION), ' Doctors')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
WHERE OCCUPATION = 'Doctor'
```

If I run the first part of my code it runs fine. But if I run the second part of my code I get this error:

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ' , COUNT(OCCUPATION), ' Doctors')

Comment: A database dump would be helpful.

Comment: You need a `;` between your two queries.

Comment: @Nick Nice catch +1, and you just saved me time from setting up an unnecessary demo.

Comment: I have tried. no errors on my local

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL:

```
SELECT Name + '(' + LEFT(OCCUPATION,1) + ')' FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY Name;
SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ' , COUNT(OCCUPATION),' ',LOWER(OCCUPATION), 's.') FROM OCCUPATIONS 
GROUP BY OCCUPATION 
ORDER BY COUNT(OCCUPATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(name,'(',substr(occupation,1,1),')') 
from occupations 
order by name;

Select concat('There are a total of ',count(occupation),' ',lower(occupation),'s.') 
from occupations 
group by occupation 
order by count(occupation)
```